# need to switch DP daisy-chained monitors on & off to get xrandr to switch them on

Tags: multiple-monitors, xrandr, displayport

I'm running awesomewm on an Ubuntu laptop. I have two external monitors connected in DP daisy chain configuration, plugged into laptop's mini-dp port. `xrandr` detects both when they are plugged in. However, if I just plug in the mini-dp cable and run the `xrandr` command to switch off the laptop display and switch on the two monitors, the monitors do not switch on.

If I turn the monitors on and off a few times and then run the `xrandr` command, it works properly. I say "on and off a few times" because that's what I in fact do, although it's not clear what exactly I have to do to make them work.

I'm guessing this has something to do with hardware power management in the monitors, but not totally sure. This has never happened when I, for example, ran two monitors directly from laptop outputs using different outputs (for example, one from HDMI, one from DVI, or one from HDMI, one from mini-dvi-to-hdmi). If anyone knows what's going on here or how it can be fixed or more effectively hacked around, please let me know.

Comment: Recommendations of better stack exchange site for this question are also welcome.

Comment: I've seen these same problems on Nvidia GPU desktop too. Ubuntu 16.04 and Ubuntu 16.10 still suffer from these issues.

Answer (score 1):

Found a reasonable hackaround. The following script does what I want, albeit in a kinda ugly way

```
alias xcmd='xrandr cmd to turn on monitors, turn off laptop'
alias xcmd_inv='xrandr cmd to turn off monitors, turn on laptop'
xcmd
sleep 1
xcmd_inv
sleep 1
xcmd
sleep 1
xcmd_inv
sleep 1
xcmd
```

That's not the real script, but hopefully clear enough to anyone trying to deal with this.